# ASP Core "There was no endpoint listening at [url] that could accept the message. "

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have ASP core application which using WCF service.

Eg:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
client.SomeMetod();
```

I have new computer (old was win 7, new win 10).

I have exactly same project which was working, but now I get this error:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345/Service.svc that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

When I try to access service trough browser -- > OK
When I try to run app on old computer --> OK
When I try to run app on computer where is WCF hosted (so its on localhost, also win 10) --> OK

What could cause problem? Operation system, firewall, McAffee.. ?

I saw lot of pots here on stackoverflow, lot of them was editing some binding in web.config but I don't have web.config (If i understand it well web.config is generated when asp core projected is published)

Thank you for every idea...

EDIT 1 - Added generated Reference.cs file

namespace MesWCF
    {
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
 // My classes here 

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "MesWCF.IService")]
public interface IService
{
   //My methods here - example bellow

    //Example of one methods (collapsed above for brevity)
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetUserAccount", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetUserAccountResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MesWCF.FraMesUser> GetUserAccountAsync(string name, string password);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.0")]
public interface IServiceChannel : MesWCF.IService, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("dotnet-svcutil", "1.0.0.0")]
public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MesWCF.IService>, MesWCF.IService
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

    public ServiceClient() :
            base(ServiceClient.GetDefaultBinding(), ServiceClient.GetDefaultEndpointAddress())
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) :
            base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), ServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, string remoteAddress) :
            base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(remoteAddress))
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public ServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), remoteAddress)
    {
        this.Endpoint.Name = endpointConfiguration.ToString();
        ConfigureEndpoint(this.Endpoint, this.ClientCredentials);
    }

    public ServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

  //Methods here 

  //Example of one method (collapsed above for brevity)
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MesWCF.FraMesUser> GetUserAccountAsync(string name, string password)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetUserAccountAsync(name, password);
    }
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task OpenAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginOpen(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndOpen));
    }

    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task CloseAsync()
    {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).BeginClose(null, null), new System.Action<System.IAsyncResult>(((System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject)(this)).EndClose));
    }

    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService))
        {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            return result;
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }

    private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if ((endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService))
        {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://10.208.132.246:12345/Service.svc");
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }

    private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetDefaultBinding()
    {
        return ServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService);
    }

    private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetDefaultEndpointAddress()
    {
        return ServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService);
    }

    public enum EndpointConfiguration
    {

        BasicHttpBinding_IService,
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does `trough browser` mean the `browser` in this **new computer**? If you create a new .net console app to access WCF Service in this new computer, will it work? How did you generate the `ServiceClient` code, generated by Service Provider or copy from other project?

Comment: Yes. When I create console app (.net core 2.1) i receive same error. When I create WPF app - service is working fine. For wpf i see in  network activity (task manager -> resource manager --> network --> tpc connection) process with name of the app. But when I try to run webapp there is process dotnet - only on working computer. On new computer I don't see it  (becasue of exception).

Comment: How did you generate the client code in `.net core`? It seems to be related with the genertaed code since it works with `WPF` on this new computer.

Comment: I added service through "Add connected service". So whole code is auto generated and I just use `client.DoWork()`. But I took working version of this project (from old computer) and it doesn't work.. even if i try to add service on new computer (all is successful) but when i try to communicate --> endpoint error.

Comment: Could you share us the generated reference.cs? Does this project work if you move it to another windows 10 computer? Does this `.net core` leave behind any vpn? Try to disable the firewall.

Comment: Yes I added it to answer - i just removed my defined classes and methods for brevity. I tried it on my boss computer --> also not working. But I have virtual W10 where is also hosted WCF service --> Working fine (only difference is that insted of IP address I am using localhost:port...) I already tried disable firewall (McAfee) still not working. I am home at now and I am connected throuh VPN to office and now is my service working. And when I am at work (directly connected to network --> not working. So It has to be some problem with connection right?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to be related with connection, and it is strange you could access wsdl address, but fail to connect the service in the same computer. Does the service host behind any VPN? Did this service implement security? Have you open input port for `12345`  in service computer?

Comment: Yeah without problem and also from Wpf.. But If I check resource manager - dotnet.exe (this process is  on working computer connected to wcf address) won't event start so there must be something which making trouble even before. I am not sure with this. It's virtual computer in corporate network (so same domain).. You mean security through ISS or something else? I don't have much experience in networking. Yes should be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a sollution.

I find out, that I am able to use service from home through VPN.
So I searched some problem where are people able to access through VPN.

It was problem with proxy -  [This post](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1592) helped me fix problem.

According to mconnew's answer:

> HttpClient in `.Net Core` doesn't use `WinINet` which picks up its proxy
>   settings from the same place as you configure `IE/Edge` proxy settings.
>   It uses `WinHTTP` instead which maintains its own proxy settings. From
>   an administrative command prompt execute the command `netsh winhttp
>   reset proxy` to reset `WinHTTP` to use direct connections instead. If you
>   want to see what it's currently set as, execute the command `netsh`
>   `winhttp show proxy` before you modify it. It looks like your IT
>   department probably missed resetting this configuration when getting
>   rid of the proxy.

So I tried `netsh winhttp show proxy` on both computers.

New computer had some reccords about proxy and old none.
Then I tried `netsh winhttp reset proxy`  then i had same WinHTTP proxy settings as old computer.

Then I was able to use WCF service :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

1 - Configure correctly IIS for WCF (`step 6, If IIS does not open and gives any error, then you have to first enable IIS from Windows features. For this, follow the below steps`):

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/hosting-wcf-service-on-iis/

2 - Enable Windows features for WCF:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/blambert/2009/02/13/how-to-enable-iis7asp-net-and-wcf-http-activation/

Comment: I think IIS is configured correctly beucase two computers working properly. I also checked these functions (checked them with working computers) and even if I allow them still same error.

Comment: Do you have svc file?

Comment: Yes svc file is hosted on server (wcf service). I already used lot of methods from this service.. But on new computer I keep getting this error.