# It throws EndpointNotFoundException even though it is an Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, endpoint

To get the report we send the data from our main project to the report service.
The main project was developed with .net 3.1.Service type: WCF. To use the service, we add it to the project as a service reference. We can use the sub-methods of the service as follows.

```
WebService1SoapClient service = new WebService1SoapClient(WebService1SoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.WebService1);

var serviceOutput = await service.ReportsAsync(modelService);
```

When I run the program in local and want to get a report, I can get a report without any error. But when I try to run it on the server side, I get the following error. Can you help me?

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://xxx.xxx.com/WebService1.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Endpoints in web.config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ReportServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ReportServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" transferMode="Streamed">
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="4194304" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportServiceBehavior" name="[ProjectName].ReportPages.ReportService1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportServiceBinding" contract="DevExpress.XtraReports.Service.IReportService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:
1.The endpoint address can be defined in the configuration.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportServiceBehavior" name="[ProjectName].ReportPages.ReportService1">
     <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.com/WebService1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportServiceBinding" contract="DevExpress.XtraReports.Service.IReportService" />
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

2.I suggest you to find out if there is an application on the server that is listening on the port, and no other program is listening on the port, and you have not set any firewall rules to block the service port.
3.Try to enable display failure by setting this parameter to true in the configuration. `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults = "True" />`. Hope this will provide more detailed information.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. I added the address to the endpoint but it didn't work. In addition, we host the report service on a service provider's server. When I contacted the service provider, he stated that there was no problem in the firewall settings.
Do I need to add the IncludeException setting to the main program or the service?

Comment: You can try to set [includeExceptionDetailInFaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/service-debug-behavior) to true in web.config, or you can [Enable Tracing] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing?redirectedfrom=MSDN) A wcf service to help you diagnose the exact problem. You can see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653653/asp-core-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message) is helpful.

Comment: As you said, I added the includeException setting to the web.config file. but the error message has not changed.

Comment: You can take a look at these posts and see if it helps.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b7d650a-8d79-4357-8c38-32337d327b58/problems-with-hosting-wcf-service-on-iis-using-was-for-nettcp-bindings?forum=wcf  &&  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/213a1aec-f827-4de3-b914-e5b3bdba2f1b/configuring-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-error?forum=aspwcfasmx

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59fee508-2ebc-4dca-8e95-15a3814d085d/move-secure-wcf-service-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-https?forum=aspwcfasmx && https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f361a204-7ad2-4ecc-a20d-c92dcb4f4957/wcf-returns-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-xxx-that-could-accept-the-message?forum=wcf